# Why can't Visual Studio compile my QT Project because it doesn't find the libraries?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, qt

I have a project that compiles perfectly at school. However, when I try to compile it, it says: "fatal error C1083: unable to open the include file: 'QtCore/QDate' : No such file or directory"

I've installed QT properly, the environment variables are set and in the project I included this: "C:\Qt\4.7.4\include"

Does someone have any clue?

Comment: Have you install the Qt Visual Studio plugin?  It doesn't work for the Express versions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well the error is pretty clear: it can't find the header file.

So make sure that you have added the correct include path to the projects properties (Configuration Properties -> C/C++ -> General -> Additional Include Directories). Double check that you did this for **all the build targets** (debug, release, etc).

Next do a manual check, by appending the included 'QtCore/QDate' to the path you added to the project properties, and if the resulting full file path points to the actual file you want to include.

Also check the global visual studio settings for any conflicting include paths: Tools -> Options -> Project and Solutions -> VC++ Directories -> Include files